# Does expiry date have any affect in MemoryCacheClient?

Tags: c#, servicestack

If `XRedisClientManager` is used for ServiceStack cache, then redis itself will be able to enforce the lifetime. This isn't going to have any affect if `MemoryCacheClient` is used instead, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've registered to use [ServiceStack's RedisClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/) as the [ICacheClient cache provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching) then only the Redis Client will be used for all caching, and any API call that includes an **expiryDate** just gets forwarded to Redis.

This doesn't affect `MemoryCacheClient` simply because it doesn't get used, only the one you've registered in your IOC does. Although when using the MemoryCacheClient the entries aren't automatically expired behind-the-scenes but instead are invalidated manually whenever access to an expired entry is attempted.

Comment: I am using `MemoryCacheClient`, I was just comparing it to Redis one. I would like to use it as a temporary storage, and instead of manually clearing it it would be great if the items timed out automatically. I guess that's not possible with `MemoryCacheClient`

Comment: It doesn't clear all expired entries automatically behind the scenes, but does so individually when you try to access an expired entry.

Comment: Oh, that's insightful. Is that true for both `MemoryCacheClient` and `Redis`?

Comment: No the Redis server (i.e. the external process itself) takes care of expiring the entries so the Redis Client doesn't need to explicitly invalidate them itself.

Comment: Cool, thanks. Could you make that comment about expiry part of answer? That answered my question.

Comment: Ok done. Also in future can you please ask less ambiguous questions, as it's hard to know what answer was expected here.